# Откуда берется черная полоса у видео?

Tags: javascript, css, видео

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Черная полоса - фон у родителя в котором тег video. Убрать фон, визуально ее не будет видно. Но отступ останется...
Что это такое у тега video?

Все возможные свойства применил к тегу videо, не помогает...

Comment: Вангую, это та самая чёрная полоса именно блока `video`, сам контент видео не соответствует размерам блока из-за чего она появляется. Например блок 100x100px, а видео 100x98px, получается снизу и сверху будет чёрная полоса в 1px.

Comment: Ну и т.к. автор не оставил код, приходится только гадать.

Comment: Убрал "<!DOCTYPE html>" из html разметки, все встало на свои места. Вопрос на сколько критично без указания типа документа.

Comment: Хоть бы почитали для чего он нужен, вот [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/html/%21doctype) например.